# acer aspire one AOA150 netbook

Tags: 11.10, wireless, acer, aspire

After I installed the 11.10 version my wifi card recognizes all available networks. However after I put in the right password it tries to connect and reconnect etc. I didn t have any issues with previous ubuntu versions. Anyone got around this problem ? It seems it has something definately to do with the new 11.10 version

Answer (score 1):

No I know the solution: a bit strange I have to admit.

I had to login into my router and make it a non protected wifi (no password required). I connected without a password and without a problem. Then I put it on WPA/WPA2 again like before. Now it connects with the same password. Very strange but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I started experiencing similar problems after upgrading ubuntu to 11.10 on an Acer 532h netbook.

As one of the other commenters, I have been trying to fix this issue by using 'wicd' network manger instead of the default 'network-manager' and 'network-manager-gnome'. After trying this with no immediate result I've researched this issue further and found that this problems seems to affect many different laptops and not Acer branded ones specifically.

If, like me, you have the specific "Bad Password" error when using wicd and WPA encryption, one of the solutions suggested here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wicd/+bug/540070
might bring you closer to a solution.

Do note, that I haven't been able to get my wifi working in a stable way in Ubuntu yet, but I am convinced my problem (and possibly yours!) is related to this issue.

My wireless is working fine if I boot into windows 7 on the netbook, and other wireless devices are connecting without issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have/had the same problem. After installing Ubuntu 11.10, I also installed the "Gnome Desktop" (as I don't like Unity). However my wifi connection kept failing with the message "connection failed". So I installed synaptic so that I could un-install the network-manager and then installed "wicd". I now use wicd to connect to my router wirelessly.

Comment: I did the same: uninstall the network manager and install wicd. But it says "bad password", while I know it is the correct password. What else could be the problem ? It detects all the networks but am not able to connect.